# Copy certain region with the help of search and append on main Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 200+ Excel spreadsheets with the same structure. On these sheets the value for *Theme* is always in cell C2 and the value for *Date* is always in C7, but when it comes to *Root_cause* and *Solutions* they start from different rows.

[image: https://imgur.com/aIxHJtH]

I need to copy this information on the main sheet and append it:

[image]

Maybe it's a good idea to use the find function to find the word 'Root_cause', then choose one column to the right and drag down to copy all related rows?

Code:

```vb
Sub Protocol()
Dim wsheet As Worksheet

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
    For Each wsheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If wsheet.Name <> "Main" Then

                Set Date = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                Set Theme = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                Set Root_cause = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                Set Solutions = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

                Date.Value = wsheet.Range("C7").Value
                Theme.Value = wsheet.Range("C2").Value
                #Then I need to use FIND function on each sheet, come to word 'Root_cause', choose all rows for Root_cause and Solutions, copy them and append on sheet "Main"

                End If

        Debug.Print wsheet.Name
    Next wsheet

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I dont follow your problem. What is the relation between "Root_cause" and "Solutions" to "theme" and "date". In other words how do you know what to copy? it just does not make sense?

Comment: Each Sheet except 'Main' contains following information:
1) Date - value fixed for each sheet and it's "C7"
2) Theme - value fixed for each sheet and it's "C2"
3) Root_cause - value is contained in the column "C"
4) Solutions - value is contained in the column "D"
Basically tables with headers "Root_cause" and "Solutions" start in different rows (some from 20, some from 23) otherwise I would just copy these tables from rows 20 to LastRow and appended it to the main sheet

Comment: do you want to find the root cause based on the the text from theme? and than paste it onto main sheet?

Comment: I updated comment, sorry

Comment: Oh! so your issue is simply to find  at what row "root cause" starts and then you want to copy to main? Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: The value of 'Root_cause' and 'Solutions' to be precise. And the amount of rows for these headers can differ.

Comment: Is it possible to use Find function somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to use the find function and limit to the cells right below the  "rootcause" label.

```
Sub SelectActualUsedRange()

Dim FirstCell As Range, LastCell As Range

Set LastCell = Cells(Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

Set FirstCell = Cells(Cells.Find(What:="root_cause", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
Cells.Find(What:="root_cause", After:=LastCell, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

Range(FirstCell.Offset(1, 0), LastCell.Offset(0, -5)).Copy

End Sub
```

note I created two sheets one with the "rootcause" starting at row 13 and another starting at row 25. The rest is simply selecting the main sheet and pasting the "rootcause" values onto that sheet.
here is the image of the two separate sheets.

[image]

EDIT: notice that I'm only selecting the two columns in the middle from where "rootcause" is found all the way down to the last nonempty cell.

Comment: What does "*" accomplishes when you're setting LastCell?

Comment: How do I find "root_cause" then just choose column "solutions" next to it and then choose all rows? The reason I'm asking is because there can be some other columns so using your code they might be selected as well

Comment: It finds the last row in other words the last none empty cell you can read more about it here https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/.  You can see it in action if you step through the code using your f8 key within VBA macro editor.

Comment: do you want to limited to just the solution column? I'll edit the code to reflect just one column

Comment: checkout my updated answer , I limit how many columns to copy using `offset` so if I added a third column to my sheet only the first two columns would be selected for copy.

Comment: It's not selecting just these two columns anyways!

Comment: I've updated my code, you have to change my code to match your sheet. Unless i have your workbook exactly it is nearly impossible to give you the exact code. The code I'm providing you gives you the way to find the "rootcause" and the non empty columns beside it . You than copy select main and execute paste with vba.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GXQwtSQ   Sometimes it's not working for some reason... could it be because some cells are merged?

Comment: Sorry but from your image I can't tell what is not working. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I wanted it to select just next column when Im setting offset to -2

Comment: Can you share your workbook with me. I can help you better if I had the exact data and sheet.

Comment: How do I send it to you? is it possible in stackoverflow?

Comment: no not through stack overflow but you can uploaded to a git repo and I pull it from there.

Comment: https://ufile.io/bjosn
Also, how is it possible to store all root_cause and solution values  in one cell as I loop through them?
Thanks!

Comment: Hey, many thanks to you for helping me, I'll mark solution as solved, I decided to go with different solution! Could you please check :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756076/getting-438-error-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method